# javascript typeError: cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, class, typeerror

I'm attempting to create a stack class in Javascript, but I keep getting variations of the above error. I know that it is the constructor, but I just can't find where the problem is. Here's my class:

```js
"use strict"

class Stack {
    constuctor() {
        this.items = [];
    }

    emptyArray() {
        if (this.items === 0) {
            this.error = "The stack is empty";
        }
        return this.error;
    }

    isEmpty() {
        return this.items === 0;
    }

    push(x) {
        return this.items.push(x);
    }

    pop() {
        if (this.items >= 1) {
            return this.items.pop();
        }
        else {
            throw new emptyArray();
        }
    }

    size() {
        return this.items.length;
    }

    peak() {
        let el1 = this.items.pop();
        let el2 = this.items.pop();
        this.items.push(el2);
        this.items.push(el1);
        return el2;
    }
}

new Stack().size();
```

Comment: For example, if I try stack.push(x), I'll get a "cannot read property push" or if I use stack.size(), I'll get "cannot read property length" etc.

Comment: are you sure that your variable is defined? try using `alert()` to  see if it is defined or not.

Comment: To see if an array is empty don't use this `this.items === 0`. Use this `this.items.length === 0`! Compare the length not the array itself!

Comment: You're right, that was silly of me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`constructor` is misspelled:

```
constuctor() {
    this.items = [];
}
```

Comment: It happens to everybody :)